# Remove a deleted shared folder from a VirtualBox instance?

Tags: mount, virtualbox, fstab, automount

I have VBox 6.x running on Win 8.1, with Ubuntu 18.04x64 Guest.

I reloaded an old Ubuntu image I had created and it still has references to a shared folder (that was formerly automounted) in the /media directory and I can't figure out how to remove it.

I've checked `/etc/rc.local`, `/etc/fstab`, and the instance config and nothing in there points to where this mount is coming from.

So the mount in question `/media/sf_sharedhome` is empty since the folder it had pointed to on the Host machine is now gone.

Though when I try to use `umount` it says the folder is "not mounted"; ok maybe it's not. How do I remove this phantom reference?

In searching, I cant find anything online that addresses my particular use-case. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remove the reference from the Virtualbox Manager on your host (*Settings --> Shared Folders*, I believe).